# jQuery .each function not persisting global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function whereby I wish to run a `.each` loop and return the running total of the values

At the end of my `.each` function, the `amountSold` variable is 0 and during the `.each` loop, it is shown as undefined. What am I doing wrong?

```
function processChange(currentTarget) {
    var amountSold = 0;  //VARIABLE DECLARED
    //limit these operations to the currentlySelected tab
    var availableFundContainer = $(currentTarget).closest(".available-content").parent();

    var fundBeingSold = $(availableFundContainer.children(0)).attr('data-investment-code');

    availableFundContainer.find('.available-handler').each(function (index, val) {       
        var origVal = $(this).attr('data-original-value');
        var currentSliderVal = $(this).next('.available-content').find('.slider').slider("value");
        var amountSold = amountSold + (origVal - currentSliderVal); //PROBLEM LINE!!!!!
....}
```

Comment: You're *re-declaring* the variable with `var` inside the callback.

Comment: remove the `var` in the problem line.

Comment: and also just use `amountSold += ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating a locally scoped variable, also called amountSold, inside the each callback function.

Replace

```
var amountSold = amountSold + (origVal - currentSliderVal); //PROBLEM LINE!!!!!
```

with

```
amountSold += (origVal - currentSliderVal); //PROBLEM LINE!!!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confused with how the function scope works in JS. Consider the following example:

```js
var someArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var a = 0;
var b = 0;

someArray.forEach(function(item) {
  a = a + item;
  var b = b + item;
  console.log("loop", a, b);
});

console.log("final", a, b);
```

Run the snippet, and you will see that within the loop, the variable `b` starts out as undefined. This is so, because the function passed to the `forEach` method creates a new scope, and any variables declared with the `var` statement, will override any variables that exist in the parent scope. In this case, it means that `b` ends up being `NaN`. On the other hand, `a` keeps its previous value and increments as expected.

The final console log demonstrates, that the value of `b` in the global scope was not changed by the statements executed in the loop.

This feature of JS allows a user to create a functions that do not have side effects on the global scope.

And to answer your question, you are using the `var` statement:

`var amountSold = amountSold + (origVal - currentSliderVal);`

when you should be using a simple assignment

`amountSold = amountSold + (origVal - currentSliderVal);`

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable global using

```
window.amountSold = 0
```

Inside the loop just call it the same way

```
window.amountSold += (origVal - currentSliderVal);
```